# Configuring the data of the AjaxAppender Request Log4Javascript

Tags: javascript, couchdb, log4javascript

I am very new to Log4Javascript and logging in general, so bear with me.

I am attempting to POST the logs to a CouchDB. I am receiving an error from the server:

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Document must be a JSON object"}
```

Okay cool. So its not a JSON Object, I can fix that.

Except that I can't figure out how.

The code I am using is:

```
var log = log4javascript.getLogger();

var ajaxAppender = new log4javascript.AjaxAppender(url);
var layout = new log4javascript.JsonLayout(true, false);
ajaxAppender.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
ajaxAppender.setLayout(layout);
log.addAppender(ajaxAppender);

// Test the logger
log.debug(JSON.stringify("Hello world!"));
```

Everywhere I have searched says this is the way to send it as a JSON object, so I imagine this is correct.

When I look at the request payload, I realize that the CouchDB server must not like the way it is formatted, which is like so:

```
[
{
    "logger": "[anonymous]",
    "timestamp": 1487961971605,
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "url": "url.to.couchdb",
    "message": "\"Hello world!\""
}
]
```

As you can see, it is a JSON object within an array, and I believe this is where my problem lies.

So my questions are:

- Did I miss something in setting up the `AjaxAppender` and the `JsonLayout`?
- Is there a way to change the format of the Request Payload with log4javascript?
- If not, is there a way in CouchDB that when a document is POSTed, I can intercept and change the Request Payload and continue on, so it removes the array (that I am assuming it does not like)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer.

The `JsonLayout` has properties called `batchHeader` and `batchFooter` among others, but these two were the culprits for me.

For whatever reason, it still included them even though I was not doing batch log sending, so I removed both of them like so:

```
...
var layout = new log4javascript.JsonLayout(true, false);
layout.batchHeader = "";
layout.batchFooter = "";
...
```

This fixed my problem and I successfully POSTed logs to CouchDB.

Hope this helps someone else.